# Applying aero effect to vb .net form

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to apply aero effect to vb .net forms and have come across quite a few codes though I couldn't use any to actually apply the aero effect.
The code that I have been using is:-

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure Side
    Public Left As Integer
    Public Right As Integer
    Public Top As Integer
    Public Bottom As Integer

End Structure
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("dwmapi.dll")> Public Shared Function DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef pMarinset As Side) As Integer

End Function
```

But it doesn't work and I can't find any way to actually get it working even when I create an object of Side

```
Dim s As Side = New Side
s.Left = 0
s.Right = 0
s.Top = 0
s.Bottom = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you need to set the value of the variable Left, Right, Top and Bottom as -1 and not 0.
The code should be:-

```
Dim s As Side = New Side
s.Left = -1
s.Right = -1
s.Top = -1
s.Bottom = -1
Me.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

this should make your form have aero effect with blue color

Comment: I thought we were setting the code to stretch out top panel so that it covers the screen thats why I set the distance to 0

Comment: we are actually setting the margin between the different sides of the outer border of the form that has aero effect on it by default. So we set the intermediate margins as -1